# Data binding in b-card title

Tags: vue.js

How can I data bind a data in the the title of a b-card in bootstrap-vue

```html
<b-card header="{{month}}} test runs" header-tag="header">
```

Currently this is what I have and I got an error

Comment: What error? Have you tried `:header="month"`?

Comment: I want to combine the month data and "test runs" text

Comment: Try `:header="month + ' test runs'"`, then (it's just a JavaScript expression). Or make a computed property for the text.

Comment: I got an undefined

Comment: Please give more info. You're saying stuff like "I got an error" and "I got an undefined" but the error messages you're getting should include more info than that. **What** variable is it saying is undefined?

Comment: Use title instead of header if you want a bigger sized text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a computed property for this:

```
computed: {
   headerText() {
      return this.month + ' test runs';
   }
}
```

Now use this as a value of `header`

```
<b-card :header="headerText" header-tag="header">
```

Comment: I got an error Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'headerText' in undefined

Comment: @Dranier sure you have added the computed property the correct way? Try hardcoding the return statement..

Comment: Make sure you fix the `retutn` typo, too. It should say `return`.